# Creating installer for operating system Cosmos C#

Tags: c#, installation, operating-system, cosmos

I need to create an installer for my operating system in Cosmos kernel but I don't know where to start or how to create it.

[See my Operating system]

https://www.mediafire.com/file/3nr6pbjfg7p1gfq/GoPixelOS.iso/file

I want to install the OS on the machine, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help you. but it actually makes a new user. but it still needs installation. but this won't work for another computer that does not have Filesystem.vmdk. maybe it is just a virtual file system

1. First you will need a file system
2. you will also need System.io
3. on before writing this code⬇

   ```
    if (!File.Exists("0:\\youros\\System.txt")) //you will need Using.System.io and ! mean not equal
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("YourOS will be install in your pc");
            Console.WriteLine("Create a username and password:");
            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string cPassword = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(username +"> "); //when your put username variable it should look like this "The user name: "
            Console.WriteLine("Creating System Directory..."); //Creating Directory or folder
            fs.CreateDirectory("0:\\yourOS\\");
            Console.WriteLine("Creating File for user");
            fs.CreateFile("0:\\yourOS\\System.txt"); //Creating File System
            fs.CreateFile("0:\\yourOS\\users.db");
            fs.CreateFile("0:\\yourOS\\password.db"); //creating a password files
            Console.WriteLine("Setting User Preferences...");
            File.WriteAllText("0:\\yourOS\\System.txt", write);
            File.WriteAllText("0:\\yourOS\\users.db", username); `    //This will save username
            File.WriteAllText("0:\\yourOS\\password.db", cPassword); //this one will save the user password
            Console.WriteLine("Reboot ONEOS in 3 seconds");
            Cosmos.HAL.Global.PIT.Wait(3000);
            Sys.Power.Reboot(); //when the installation done it will reboot`



    else //after reboot it will go to else and just leave it blank. it will just go to run() after the else
    {
       password = File.ReadAllText("0:\\oneos\\password.db"); //this will show the   
       Console.Write("Type your password: ")
       var type Console.ReadLine();
       if (type == password)
       {
          //just leave it blank. it will go to protected override void run()
       }
       else
       }
         Sys.Power.Reboot(); //this will reboot the OS if user type wrong password
       {

    }
   ```

That is for the installation but if you want the installation to be more useful you will need this

```
//protected override void Run()
text = File.ReadAllText("0:\\oneos\\users.db"); //this will show the username
Console.Write(text + "> ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
```

And that is if you want to make it show error put try and catch to your OS if there has an error.
if you can understand this you can make the os have user selection like windows logon screen.

If there is a problem please tell me

Comment: i will try, thanks!

Comment: if there is a problem please tell me. sometimes the installation is not stable.

Comment: I Want To Make It Like Overwrite The System Files To make The C:// Partition Boot It